# OWL Carousel - анимация нескольких итемов

Tags: javascript, slider, анимация, карусель, jcarousel

Доброго времени суток, столкнулся со следующей проблемой:

Использую [Owl карусель](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/), хочу поставить анимацию для двух итемов:

```
animateOut: 'fadeOut',
transitionStyle : "fade"
```

Но как я понял, она работает только если выводится один итем `singleItem : true` или `items : 1`.

---

Подскажите пожалуйста как решить эту проблему :?

Comment: Это не проблема. Это правильная реализация. Какой смысл в исчезновении и появлении всего слайдера? Когда итем один это оправдано - старый исчезает, а новый появляется.

Comment: @SlyDeath , смысла нету, вы не поняли, у меня выводится два слайда, а `transitionStyle : "fade"` работает только когда он выводится по один(

Comment: В документации написано: "**transitionStyle - Add CSS3 transition style. Works only with one item on screen**". Это не ошибка, это реализация и не работает она с несколькими именно потому, почему я описал выше. Это анимация смены одного слайда на другой. Если бы работало на много слайдов, то исчезали бы все слайды и появлялись с новым, скрыв один старый. Для того, что нужно вам - необходимо перегрузить нужную функцию и реализовать как нужно вам.

Comment: @SlyDeath, в том то и вопрос - как это сделать?)

Comment: заказывайте разработку кода, если сами не можете. :) Я для Совы делал свои дописки, но за Вас писать не буду, времени нету. :)

Comment: @SlyDeath, я так понимаю, это не пара строк кода? просто думал что накинуть другой эффект будет проще(